# How to Pass Raw query from controller to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dapper

I want to pass raw query from `Controller` to `Model`. I wrote ConnectionString in model and also How can write `ExecuteWithReturn` and `ExecuteWithOutReturn` function in model

This is my Sample Code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult  RawQuery(int? EmployeeID)
{
     if (EmployeeID == null)
     {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     }
     else
     {
         string query = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeID =@EmployeeID";
         DapperORM.ExecutewithReturn(query);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
}
```

Model:

```
    public static class DapperORM
{

     public static void ExecuteWithOutReturn(string sql)
      {
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
     {
        //which code can I write here to execute row query without  return  
     }
 }

 public static void ExecuteWithReturn(string sql)
 {
      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
      {
          //which code can I write here to execute row query with  return
      }
 }
```

}

Comment: i want pass raw query from controller to model, in model class i want execute sql query only delete and insert function to return the value i need to function in model withreturn and withoutreturn function which code can i write in model class

Comment: look at dapper docs https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example Code :

```
public static void ExecuteWithoutReturn(string sql) {
      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
          //which code can I write here to execute row query with out return
          connection.Execute(sql, commandType : CommandType.Text); 
      }
 }

//Generic method to fetch List 
public static IEnumerable<T> ExecuteWithReturn<T>(string sql) //pass return type of list
{
      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
           return connection.Query<T>(sql).ToList();
     }
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer hope it will help you.

Comment: I used above update code but its not working for me.

Comment: ExecuteWithoutReturn its working but ExecutewithReturn its not working could u plz explain above code.

Comment: How To return all employee record in index viewpage using above code.what is meant by Result and Entity